# Best Way To Self-Host a Webserver and stay "Anonymous"?

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, vpn

I have gotten into making web pages with apache/nginx and I want to know whats the best way to have either a proxy or a VPN setup so whenever anyone points at my domain they won't get my IP so easily

The Domain should auto change the IP if it sees any changes so that shouldn't be a problem 
I wanted to make a proxy list into a file and use it but I haven't really find a way yet
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a reverse proxy with nginx and apache i.e. when someone tryies to access your website by typing in your domain, their web browser will query a domain name server to get the IP address associated with you're domain. Their web browser will then send a request to your nginx server IP which will then in turn send a request via reverse proxy to your apache server IP where the physical web page files are located.  Apache IP address returns the requested web page files to nginx IP address and nginx in turn returns the requested web page files to the client IP address.

Comment: okay can you give me an example of that configuration or a link? also I am using a subdomain from freedns that isn't a problem?

Comment: No I figured you'd have the sense to Google it

Comment: ok but what you are suggesting is about the internal ip being protected or just having another ip a middle man what i was asking is about External IP

Comment: You do not understand IPv4 or IPv6 headers. In order for a packet to be sent over the internet there has to be a destination IP address. You can not send a request to a sever without having a destination IP address in the IPv4/IPv6 header. You cloud look at .onion sites on the tor network but they are incredibly slow due to limited bandwidth it's like dial up 30 years ago.

Comment: yes you do need to ask for a destination IP but the IP of my domain is refreshed automatically therefore I can use a VPN or etc and it will be different than my IP

Comment: how is someone sending a request to your server, how do they know what the destination IP is ?

Comment: my domain is registered on freedns there it is associated with the IP of the server aka my IP the server while running every x seconds sends an communication to see if there were changes to the IP and sends a request to change it on freedns?

Comment: Domain name servers do not update instantaneously it can take several hours for DNS records to propagate. This will result in client requests failing to reach your server.

Comment: its a sacrifice that im willing to make for privacy I'm not gonna make a website that is gonna turn into google with that much traffic also i have tested it it is around 30m to 45m for full removal of the domain but just changing the IP should be faster

Comment: Your original question was "whenever anyone points at my domain they won't get my IP so easily" . People will get your IP really easy, they just need to type in your domain and the dns will give them your ip

Comment: Yes by my IP i meant my Real Public IP of my router and my network by using a VPN or similar it prevents that

Comment: Once again how are clients going send a request to your server if they do not have an IP address, you going to call up noord vpn and tell them that you want them to run a server for you or something, your not making much sense

Comment: yea you are correct so do i have any option to do what I meant? or my only option to do it is making it on the tor network instead of clearnet?